# Spring 4 and Xfire 1.2.6 IllegalArgumentException

Tags: spring, web-services, spring-ws, xfire

When I am integrating Xfire 1.2.6 with Spring4, I am getting following error:

```
SEVERE: Context initialization failed
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'xfire.customEditorConfigurer' defined in class path resource [org/codehaus/xfire/spring/customEditors.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert property value of type 'java.util.LinkedHashMap' to required type 'java.util.Map' for property 'customEditors'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert value of type [org.codehaus.xfire.spring.editors.ServiceFactoryEditor] to required type [java.lang.Class] for property 'customEditors[org.codehaus.xfire.service.ServiceFactory]': PropertyEditor [org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.ClassEditor] returned inappropriate value of type [org.codehaus.xfire.spring.editors.ServiceFactoryEditor]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:547)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:198)
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:167)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:609)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4811)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5251)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1092)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1834)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert property value of type 'java.util.LinkedHashMap' to required type 'java.util.Map' for property 'customEditors'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert value of type [org.codehaus.xfire.spring.editors.ServiceFactoryEditor] to required type [java.lang.Class] for property 'customEditors[org.codehaus.xfire.service.ServiceFactory]': PropertyEditor [org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.ClassEditor] returned inappropriate value of type [org.codehaus.xfire.spring.editors.ServiceFactoryEditor]
at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertIfNecessary(BeanWrapperImpl.java:479)
at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertForProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:511)
at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertForProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:505)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.convertForProperty(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1502)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1461)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1197)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
... 25 more
      Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert value of type [org.codehaus.xfire.spring.editors.ServiceFactoryEditor] to required type [java.lang.Class] for property 'customEditors[org.codehaus.xfire.service.ServiceFactory]': PropertyEditor [org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.ClassEditor] returned inappropriate value of type [org.codehaus.xfire.spring.editors.ServiceFactoryEditor]
at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:263)
at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertToTypedMap(TypeConverterDelegate.java:623)
at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:208)
at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertIfNecessary(BeanWrapperImpl.java:459)
... 31 more
```

Jar which are used for this are:

```
activation-1.1.jar
ant-1.5.jar
aopalliance-1.0.jar
bcprov-jdk15-133.jar
commons-attributes-api-2.1.jar
commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar
commons-codec-1.3.jar
commons-discovery-0.2.jar
commons-httpclient-3.0.jar
commons-logging-1.1.3.jar
javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar
javax.servlet.jsp-api-2.3.1.jar
jaxb-api-2.0.jar
jaxb-impl-2.0.1.jar
jaxb-xjc-2.0.1.jar
jaxen-1.1-beta-9.jar
jaxws-api-2.0.jar
jdom-1.0.jar
jmock-1.0.1.jar
jsr173_api-1.0.jar
jstl-1.2.jar
junit-3.8.1.jar
mail-1.4.jar
opensaml-1.0.1.jar
qdox-1.5.jar
saaj-api-1.3.jar
saaj-impl-1.3.jar
spring-aop-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar
spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar
spring-core-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar
spring-expression-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar
spring-web-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar
spring-webmvc-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar
stax-api-1.0.1.jar
stax-utils-20040917.jar
wsdl4j-1.6.1.jar
wss4j-1.5.1.jar
wstx-asl-3.2.0.jar
xbean-2.2.0.jar
xbean-spring-2.8.jar
xercesImpl-2.7.1.jar
xfire-aegis-1.2.6.jar
xfire-all-1.2.6.jar
xfire-annotations-1.2.6.jar
xfire-core-1.2.6.jar
xfire-generator-1.2.6.jar
xfire-java5-1.2.6.jar
xfire-jaxb2-1.2.6.jar
xfire-jaxws-1.2.6.jar
xfire-jsr181-api-1.0-M1.jar
xfire-spring-1.2.6.jar
xfire-ws-security-1.2.6.jar
xfire-xmlbeans-1.2.6.jar
xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar
xmlParserAPIs-2.6.2.jar
XmlSchema-1.1.jar
xmlsec-1.3.0.jar
```

Given that bug https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/10825 (formerly SPR-6157) has already been fixed, I'm  not sure why such issue is occurring.